When You place a bunch of electrons on a handkerchief by rubbing can you influence their polarity orientations by a strong magnet?
We all know that we can basically obtain a considerable number of charges on a material just by mechanical work.When all of that electrons are for a time period in one place can we orient all of their spins in just one direction by the influence of a strong e.g. neodymium magnet?Thanks for any help...

How electrons are going to respond to an applied magnetic field depends very strongly on the nature of their interactions with the matrix of particles they are interacting with, so this is really not an answerable question.
